# how to build an object like another object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are some inputs. I have generated an object from the value of those inputs. So, my generated object is something like this:

```
var generate_fields = {
  name: "Mike",
  email: "mike@gmail.com",
  gender: "1",
  hobby: ["travel", "movie"]
}
```

And there is a reference object:

```
var ref_obj = {
    personal_information: {
      name: null,
      password: null,
      gender: null
  },
  business_information: {
    email: null,
    id: null,
  },
  special_information: {
    hobby: null,
    achievement: null
  }
}
```

I need to create a new object using an object, `generate_fields` like reference object, `ref_obj`. So, the new object will be:

```
var custom_obj = {
    personal_information: {
     name: "Mike",  
     gender: "1",
  },
  business_information: {
    email: "mike@gmail.com",
  },
  special_information: {
    hobby: ["travel", "movie"]
  }
}
```

How to make `custom_obj` using `generate_fields` and `ref_obj`?

**Demo:**

```js
var ref_obj = {
 personal_information: {
   name: null,
    password: null,
    gender: null
  },
  business_information: {
   email: null,
    id: null,
  },
  special_information: {
   hobby: null,
    achievement: null
  }
}

//console.log(ref_obj);

$('form').submit(function(event) { 
 event.preventDefault();
  var generated_fields = {};
  $(this).find('input, select').not('input[name=submit]').each(function() {
   generated_fields[this.name] = $(this).val();
  });
  console.log(generated_fields);
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <laberl>Name: </laberl>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
      <option value="1">Male</option>
      <option value="2">Female</option>
      <option value="2">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Hobbies:</label>
    <select name="hobby" id="hobby" multiple>
      <option value="books">Reading books</option>
      <option value="travel">Travelling</option>
      <option value="movie">Movie</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You basically want a constructor. Either use a class or just a function to create your object.

Comment: Use { ...firstObj, ...secondObj }

Comment: @Daryll Did you read the question? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use generic solution [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) + [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach). Let me try to describe my approach. First of all you should iterate over generated_fields array to determine root level fields and then you have to iterate over each field and check if original object contains the same property

```js
var a1 = {
  name: "Mike",
  email: "mike@gmail.com",
  gender: "1",
  hobby: ["travel", "movie"]
}

var a2 = {
    personal_information: {
      name: null,
      password: null,
      gender: null
  },
  business_information: {
    email: null,
    id: null,
  },
  special_information: {
    hobby: null,
    achievement: null
  }
}

const arr = Object.keys(a2).reduce((a, key) => {
 Object.keys(a2[key]).forEach(value => {
  if(a1.hasOwnProperty(value)){
   a[key] = a[key] || {};
   a[key][value] = a1[value];
  } 
 });
 return a;
}, {});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: can you please explain what did you mean by a in the parameter?

Comment: According to the MDN reduce documentation:

The reducer function takes four arguments:

Accumulator (acc)
Current Value (cur)
Current Index (idx)
Source Array (src)
Your reducer function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value.

Comment: so, 'a' is the Accumulator here?

Comment: Please, don't mind! I am trying to understand your code step by step. And one more question has come to my mind. Why a[key] had been assigned with `{}` by `||` statement?

Comment: It means, that you have to do nothing with a[key] if it exists otherwise you should create it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is a simple solution without recursion. Note the switch/case section. You must place the values into each property as you specify. This is best and most readable but only if you know the fields in advance. I do not recommend this for large or dynamic objects, where you would instead use the other `.reduce`, `.forEach` answer.
2. Note, this line I changed: `var generated_fields = ref_obj;`. You may need to use `var generated_fields = {...ref_obj};` to get a copy of the object if you are creating multiple.
3. Your first `<label>` is mistyped as `<laberl>`

```js
var ref_obj = {
 personal_information: { name: null, password: null, gender: null },
  business_information: { email: null, id: null, },
  special_information: { hobby: null, achievement: null }
}

$('form').submit(function(event) { 
 event.preventDefault();
  var generated_fields = ref_obj;
  $(this).find('input, select').not('input[name=submit]').each(function() {
  
    switch (this.name) {
      case 'name':
      case 'password':
      case 'gender':
       generated_fields.personal_information[this.name] = $(this).val(); break;
      case 'email':
      case 'id':
        generated_fields.business_information[this.name] = $(this).val(); break;
      case 'achievement':
      case 'hobby':
       generated_fields.special_information[this.name] = $(this).val(); break;
    }
    
  });
  console.log(generated_fields);
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
      <option value="1">Male</option>
      <option value="2">Female</option>
      <option value="2">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Hobbies:</label>
    <select name="hobby" id="hobby" multiple>
      <option value="books">Reading books</option>
      <option value="travel">Travelling</option>
      <option value="movie">Movie</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my general solution to your question.

Basically I've copied the "empty" item and used a recursive function to inject the values into it.

```js
var generate_fields = {
  name: "Mike", email: "mike@gmail.com",
  gender: "1", hobby: ["travel", "movie"]
};

var ref_obj = {
  personal_information: { name: null, password: null, gender: null },
  business_information: { email: null, id: null},
  special_information:  { hobby: null, achievement: null }
};


// First, create an exact duplicate of ref_obj
var ans = {...ref_obj};

function isObject(obj) {
  return obj != null && obj.constructor.name === "Object";
}

function copyProperty(obj, name, val) {
  for (let property in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) continue;
    
    if (isObject(obj[property])) {
      // The recursive case
      copyProperty(obj[property], name, val);
    }
    else if (property === name) { // Note that obj[property] isn't an object
      // Inject the property
      obj[property] = val;
    }
  }
  
  return obj;
}

// Iterate the generate_fields object's properties, and copy each of them to 'ans'
for (let property in generate_fields) {
  if (!generate_fields.hasOwnProperty(property)) continue;
  ans = copyProperty(ans, property, generate_fields[property]);
}

console.log(ans);
```